# My .xcodeproj was transformed into folder

Tags: xcode, xcode-project

I have a problem to build my project on Xcode 6.3. I change name of my application in Xcode, and after that, my .xcodeproj was transformed into folder.

[image]

I don't know why my file was transformed into folder. Does someone could tell me how to find my file ? Thanks.

Comment: `.xcodeproj` has always been a folder, it just looks like the .xcodeproj extension was removed. Rename your folder and put `.xcodeproj` at the end of it. Finder will probably ask you if you are sure you want to do it, click yes.

Comment: Yes, it's works. I panic for nothing :-)